# Reverting a MacBook Air with only Windows on it

Tags: windows-10, macbook-air

I had an old MacBook Air (Mid 2013 model) which I no longer used and decided to repurpose as a Windows-only laptop. I formatted the hard disc on the Mac to FAT32 and installed Windows 10 on it and now it's basically a MacBook Air running only Windows 10.

Is there any way I can revert this?

Comment: Apparently Macs should have an "Internet recovery" system available since 2011 which should be accessible by pressing Cmd + R while turning your Mac on. That might allow you to recover MacOs. Otherwise https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77NKImxpjpI maybe.

Comment: You reinstalled Windows 10 to a FAT32 partition?  Are you positive that is exactly what you did?  I assume you no longer have the recovery partition?

Comment: [Internet Recovery Mode - Command + Option + R](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) appears to be the solution to your problem. [Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173947/how-do-i-get-an-operating-system-onto-a-new-hard-drive) is a good list of your options

Comment: I was stuck for some reason (can't remember why) but completely unable to install using internet recovery mode.  I was successful in using an image [downloaded from the app store](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).  Look at the page part that says "Use the App Store to download and install the latest macOS".  I wasted days and this was the only way I could get it working.  Had to make the image on another mac though.

Comment: My apologies. I got the file system wrong. It's an NTFS partition. @Ramhound

Also, I do not have access to the Recovery Partition. (the Wi-Fi on the mac doesn't work and for some reason I am unable to use ethernet when I try to access Internet Recovery mode (It keeps asking me to select a Wi-fi network. 

I might have to follow the approach suggested by SeñorCMasMas